# Creating a route with optional children

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

Is it possible to configure a "terminal" route with `children`, or in other words, a route with "optional" `children`.

I'm trying to create a routable master/detail view, where the details are not displayed initially, and the list is not destroyed when the details view is opened.

For example, navigate to `/a`, and then, without destroying `a`, navigate to `/a/1`.

**First attempt**:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  //...
  { path: 'a', component: AListComponent, children: [
    { path: ':id', component: ADetailsComponent }
  ]},
  //...
];
```

... with this configuration, the following error is thrown:

`EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'a'`

**Second attempt**:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  //...
  { path: 'a', component: AListComponent },
  { path: 'a', component: AListComponent, children: [
    { path: ':id', component: ADetailsComponent }
  ]},
  //...
];
```

... the list component is destroyed and recreated, i.e. if it has user inputs, the values are gone.

**Third attempt** - create an "Empty" component and load it by default.

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  //...
  { path: 'a', component: AListComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: EmptyComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: ADetailsComponent }
  ]},
  //...
];
```

... works, but feels like a workaround.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What about using a dummy component that doesn't display anything for the "optional" route? AFAIK what you're looking for is not supported.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks for the comment. Your suggestion is basically my third attempt - it works, but doesn't "feel right". However, if you make your comment an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. How does the approach look to you? Tour of heroes (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html) uses an *ngIf to achieve this, but using the router feels a bit better. If the empty component approach doesn't look completely terrible, this could be a way forward, at least for the time being.

Comment: IMHO if `ngIf` is a good fit mostly depends on whether you want to reflect the state in the URL. If this isn't necessary or useful than `ngIf` should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, the state should be reflected in the URL in my case. I want users to be able to navigate directly to `/a/1`, instead of opening `a/` and selecting `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty dummy component that doesn't show anything like shown in your 3rd attempt is the best way in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! I'm hoping this becomes simpler in future versions.

Answer (score 3):

An even simpler version of your 3rd attempt is to simply use an empty path with nothing else in it, not even a component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'a', component: AListComponent, children: [
    { path: '' },
    { path: ':id', component: ADetailsComponent }
  ]},
];
```

Victor Savkin has [written about componentless routes](http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes), although he doesn't go so far as to use a completely empty route like this (his examples contain either a `redirect` or a `children` property).

Depending on your setup, you can even take it a step further and remove the `/a` path. I have a `routes` declaration like this in a feature module, lazy-loaded under `path: 'module-path'`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AListComponent, children: [
    { path: '' },
    { path: ':id', component: ADetailsComponent }
  ]},
];
```

So routing to `/module-path` loads AListComponent which contains an empty `<router-outlet>`, and routing to `/module-path/5` populates the outlet with ADetailsComponent.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! This does look like an improvement.